# Adding static resources (css,js,htm) to grails 3 application

Tags: grails, grails-3.0, grails-3.1

I am beginner in grails.
I would like to add some static resources to grails app and exclude them from url mappings.
I’ve  added the following line to UrlMappings groovy:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static excludes = ['/resources/*']
...
```

But I don’t know how add resources to app and to the final war. Probably there is settings in build.gradle.
I want to open static html which can use static js/css/images.
Like this: localhost:8080/resources/index.html

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you! @emmanuel-rosa
Well, I would like to use npm package manager in my project, and there could be hundreds of js/css/other files, in resources folder. 
Probably there is robust solution, which just automatically add folder with all content to war, and process resources in it statically.
Appreciate any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Grails 2.4, static assets are managed by the [Asset Pipeline plugin](http://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/). It's well documented, but it amounts to placing static content in either:

1. grails-app/assets/javascripts
2. grails-app/assets/stylesheets
3. grails-app/assets/images

Then pull them into your GSP view with the `<asset>` tag:

```
<asset:javascript src="something.js"/>
<asset:stylesheet src="something.css"/>
<asset:image src="something.png" width="200" height="200"/>
```

It's quite easy, just read the [documentation](http://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/).

Comment: Thank you! @emmanuel-rosa Well, I would like to use npm package manager in my project, and there could be hundreds of js/css/other files, in resources folder. Probably there is robust solution, which just automatically add folder with all content to war, and process resources in it statically. Appreciate any help

Comment: Check this out: https://objectpartners.com/2015/04/29/using-gradle-and-bower-to-manage-jscss-dependencies/

Comment: Thanks! This link is useful too, http://svene.github.io/adocblog/html/2015_05_09_webjars_in_webapplications.html

Answer (score 2):

See the grails documentation on static resources.
https://gsp.grails.org/latest/guide/resources.html

Note the following information on alternatives to the asset pipeline.

> If you do not want to use the Asset-Pipeline plugin, you can serve the static assets from directories src/main/resources/public or src/main/webapp, but the latter one only gets included in WAR packaging but not in JAR packaging.